# Reason for Ant-man not disintegrating

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

I have watched *Ant-man and the Wasp*. In the post credit scene, Ant-Man's friends all disintegrate except for him, being trapped in the Quantum realm. What was the reason for why he did not also disintegrate? Is he too small to turn into dust, or is he one of *that half of* 'lucky' people that didn't turn into dust? Or is it because of something else?

Comment: (storyline)50%-50% chance. probability... (out of the storyline), Ant Man is needed in the story in Avengers 4

Comment: I disagree with this being opinion-based,There is actually an official answer to this over on SF&F, WoG says it was luck: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191511/was-ant-man-spared-because-of-his-location, and we have in-universe evidence that the stones function across realms (quantum or otherwise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Probably Ant-Man was a lucky one.

In this break-down of the post-credits scene it's said that there is correlation between Infinity-War affects and Ant-Man.

> It would appear that the rooftop scene takes place concurrently with the end of Avengers: Infinity War when Thanos snaps his fingers, randomly halving the universe.
> <sub><sup>*- [Ant-Man and the Wasp Post Credits Scene - CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/ant-man-and-the-wasp-post-credits-scenes-explained-avengers-infinity-war-thanos-snap-uk-release/)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Of course, this means they conducted that experiment/retrieval mission with full knowledge that an alien craft appeared over NYC and soon vanished THAT VERY MORNING...